# Pause and Resume download of big files from CDN (content distribution network) with dynamic url

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using this code to download files with AFNetworking:

```
NSURLRequest *fileUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url file"]];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask;

downloadTask = [self downloadTaskWithRequest:fileUrl 
                     progress:nil
                  destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
                       //Return destination path
          } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
                       //Unzipping file.. etc..                
          }];

//start and resume download
[downloadTask resume];

//pause download
[downloadTask suspend];
```

This code works fine pausing and resuming the downloads, but the server has changed to use CDN and the URLs of the files are dynamic now.

Is it possible the download with AFNetworking work with dynamic urls?

Thanks.

Comment: Yep,it should handle internally. It will work

Comment: My mistake, I forgot tell when the CDN started work and the URLs started change, I can't continue the download already started, always restarts from begin.

Answer (score 0):

I could not do just using the AFNetworking but adding [AFDownloadRequestOperation](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation) library work as I wanted.

```
//Set download operation
AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:"requestURL"
                                                                                 targetPath:"toPath"
                                                                               shouldResume:YES];

//Success and Failure callbacks
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //completion
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //error
}];

//to resume download
[operation resume];

//to pause download
[operation pause];
```